# torchaudio.io not properly using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pytorch

I am following this tutorial about hardware-accelerated gpu encoding/decoding for PyTorch [https://pytorch.org/audio/main/hw_acceleration_tutorial.html], I am encountering an error with the following code:

```
import torch
import torchaudio

print(torch.__version__) # 1.14.0.dev20221013+cu116
print(torchaudio.__version__) # 0.13.0.dev20221013+cu116
print(torchaudio._extension._FFMPEG_INITIALIZED) # True

from torchaudio.io import StreamReader
local_src = "vid.mp4"
cuda_conf = {
    "decoder": "h264_cuvid",  # Use CUDA HW decoder
    "hw_accel": "cuda:0",  # Then keep the memory on CUDA:0
}

def decode_vid(src, config):
    frames = []
    s = StreamReader(src)
    s.add_video_stream(5, **config)
    for i, (chunk,) in enumerate(s.stream()):
        frames.append(chunk[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vid = decode_vid(local_src, cuda_conf)
```

The error message (somewhat truncated) is:

> File
> "/home/james/PycharmProjects/AlphaPose/Spectronix/Early_Experiments/vid_gpu_decode.py",
> line 23, in decode_vid
> s.add_video_stream(5, **config)   File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/alphapose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchaudio/io/_stream_reader.py",
> line 624, in add_video_stream
> hw_accel, RuntimeError: Unsupported codec: "h264_cuvid".

I have an RTX 3090 ti as my GPU, which does support the h264_cuvid decoder, and I have been able to decode a video on the command line running (taken from the tutorial linked above)

```
sudo ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -i "https://download.pytorch.org/torchaudio/tutorial-assets/stream-api/NASAs_Most_Scientifically_Complex_Space_Observatory_Requires_Precision-MP4_small.mp4" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M test.mp4
```

So it seems torchaudio.io is not properly using ffmpeg. Any insights of how to fix this problem much appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: What's the format of `chunk`? Can it be numpy array?

Comment: Ultimately I'd like an np array yes, and that is what the chunks return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RuntimeError: Unsupported codec: "h264_cuvid".`

The error happens [here](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/blob/b1f510fa5681e92ee82bdc6b2d1ed896799fc32c/torchaudio/csrc/ffmpeg/stream_reader/decoder.cpp#L13-L26), and the StreamReader has not gotten to the point where it executes NVDEC-specific code, so this is generic issue with FFmpeg compatibility.

This suggests that the `libavcodec` found at runtime is not configured with `h264_cuvid`.

A possible explanation is that there are multiple installations of FFmpeg in your system and torchaudio is picking up the one without NVDEC support, while when you invoke `ffmpeg` command, the one with NVDEC support is loaded.

Perhaps you can check your system and see if there are multiple FFmpeg installations and remove the ones without NVDEC support?

Comment: Ya this is true, I did end up having an ffmpeg within my conda installation as part of the torch installation that didn't have the h264_cuvid encoder installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK stepping away from `torchaudio` (its limitation must be purely due to how the wrapper function works) you can try my [`ffmpegio` package](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) to do the similar function.

```
pip install ffmpegio
```

You can read video frames once (capture all frames till FFmpeg exits) or read a chunk at a time while FFmpeg is running along.

```py
from ffmpegio

local_src = "vid.mp4"

kwargs = {
  'vsync': 0,
  'hwaccel_in': 'cuvid' # pick one or 
#  'c:v_in': h264_cuvid  # the other
}


# to read all the frames RGB 
fs, F = ffmpegio.video.read(local_src, **kwargs)
# fs: framerate in frames/sec
# F: nframes x height x width x ncomp  numpy array

# read n frames
n = 10
fs, F = ffmpegio.video.read(local_src, vframes=n, **kwargs)
# F: n x height x width x ncomp  numpy array

# work on n frames at a time
with ffmpegio.open(local_src, blocksize=n, **kwargs) as f:
    for F in f:
        # F: n x height x width x ncomp  numpy array
```

The one thing I'm not sure of your code is

```py
    "hw_accel": "cuda:0",  # Then keep the memory on CUDA:0
```

As far as I know, there isn't a way for an outside program to tap into the CUDA memory space that is mapped to FFmpeg. The `ffmpegio` is not capable of doing this.

If you encounter any issues, feel free to post on the GitHub.

Comment: I'm not married to using torchaudio, although as you say they do seem to be able to map the output to a given gpu, and since I have a multi-gpu setup, I'd like to take advantage of decoding on potentially more than one gpu. I'll try your approach out in the coming days and let you know, thanks for the help.

Comment: Gotcha. If that's what you meant, set `"hwaccel_in": "cuda:0"` to `kwargs`.